# WebClient request retorna vazio

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Em meu programa preciso obter o conteúdo do meu site, mas o retorno do método downloadString do objeto webclient retorna nulo. O mais intrigante é que não ocorre nenhuma exceção, o status code é 200, a requisição é realizada perfeitamente porém a url não retorna nada.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
String teste = wc.DownloadString("http://www.wiplay.com.br");
```

Meu site http://www.wiplay.com.br

Comment: Quando se trata de despistar problemas de HTTP, o [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com/) é o teu maior amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que definir os headers da requisição antes de fazer a requisição:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers["Accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36";
wc.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4";
String teste = wc.DownloadString("http://www.wiplay.com.br/");
```

Acabei de testar esse código e funciona aqui.

Quando não souber quais headers e como definir os headers, use o fiddler e veja o que o navegador está mandando para o servidor do site... ai então é só uma questão de copiar os valores dos headers até funcionar.

Comment: Miguel Angelo, Muito Obrigado sua resposta foi muito construtiva erá exatamente isso, com certeza uma configuração do servidor exigindo mais headers.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar um `HttpClient` no lugar do `WebClient`:

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.wiplay.com.br");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var teste = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
} else {
    // Lógica para tratamento de status diferente de 200
}
```